# android in-app billing - optional json fields

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I try to add in-app billing to my application.

I read all the documents on the android developer site and got over the Dungeons example code.

I see in the example code, that several fields on the `PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED` message, are optional.

In which case exactly this message doesn't contain this optional field:

1) "nonce"

2) "orderId"

3) "notificationId"

Comment: @Bill The Ape: in which scenario, I do not receive the above fields?

Comment: +1 for explaining the question. AFAIK, only the "developer payload" is optional. Where did you see that nonce, orderId or notificationId is optional? I couldn't find any such reference in [the sample code](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download).